# How to combine two 1D lists into 2D array?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to read mzXML files using Pyteomics' `mzxml` class. The elements that I need to access are in `numpy.ndarray` format, which I convert as lists. The mzXML files contain several columns with lists as values. The main objective is to combine the two lists into 2D array (side by side in column-wise) so that I can save as CSV files.

I tried using `np.concatenate((mzplist, mzplist2), axis=1)`, which produced `axis=1` error saying that `axis=1` is out of bounds for 1D arrays. I also tried using `hstack`, `column_stack`. The closest I got was from `column_stack` (code below) but the resulting array was 1D when I viewed the resulting CSV files (each cell of Excel contains m/z value and intensity value separated by a space).

```
plist = []

for files in os.listdir(full_path):
    filename = os.path.basename(files)
    with mzxml.read(full_path + '\\' + filename) as reader:
        for line in reader:
            mzplist = line['m/z array'].tolist()
            mzplist2 = line['intensity array'].tolist()
            print(type(mzplist))
            mzplist = np.column_stack([mzplist, mzplist2])
            #mzplist.columns = ['mass', 'Intensity']
            np.savetxt(newfolder + '\\' + filename + '.csv', mzplist) 
            plist = []
            mzplist = []
            mzplist2 = []
```

Expected results for `mzplist`:

```
 Mass       Intensity
  1            2
  3            4
  5            6
```

Here `line['m/z array'].tolist()` yields a list `[1, 3, 5, ...]`, and `line['intensity array'].tolist()` yields a list `[2, 4, 6, ...]`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: So each list is a column? E.g., listA['Header', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3']. If not, could you clarify once more.

Comment: Have you tried `np.c_[mzplist, mzplist2]`?

Comment: @JoePatten, how is `np.c_` different from `np.column_stack`?

Comment: @hpaulj I'm not quite sure. `np.column_stack` is a function  while `np.c_` is actually a c class. Anyone else have any insight on the difference (looking at the doc strings make them look almost identical)?

Comment: @PL200 I think so. When I saved the list to a csv file, it was just a single column without any header.

Comment: @JoePatten I just tried using np.c_ but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*each cell of Excel contains m/z value and intensity value separated by a space*

I suspect problem source is that line

```
np.savetxt(newfolder + '\\' + filename + '.csv', mzplist)
```

as space is default delimiter for `np.savetxt` ([as documentation say](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)), try to replace that line with

```
np.savetxt(newfolder + '\\' + filename + '.csv', mzplist, delimiter=',')
```

and check if that would help.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I forgot about the delimiter. I knew about it but didn't think to use it.

Answer (score 1):

With 2 lists as you describe:

```
In [39]: alist=[1,3,5,7]; blist=[2,4,6,8]
```

A natural way to combine them into an array is:

```
In [40]: arr = np.array((alist, blist))
In [41]: arr
Out[41]: 
array([[1, 3, 5, 7],
       [2, 4, 6, 8]])
```

Transpose of that array looks like:

```
In [42]: arr.T
Out[42]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

Which we can write with `savetxt` as:

```
In [44]: np.savetxt('foo.txt', arr.T, fmt='%5d')
In [45]: cat foo.txt
    1     2
    3     4
    5     6
    7     8
```

`column_stack` and `c_` will produce the same array.

You can add a ',' delimiter if that is what your external reader demands.

Do you know how to read the output of a `savetxt` write as plain text? I'm using the `bash` shell `cat`.

When people have problems reading and writing `csv` files we usually ask for samples, so we can reproduce the problem.  If needed a sample of intermediate arrays (such as the output of the `column_stack`) may help.  Otherwise we are left guessing as to what the problem is.